# Ruby searching hash by criteria

Tags: ruby, hash

How do I compare an array hash to a single hash, and return a new array of hashes which contain the results from the comparison.

For example:

```
stored_hash  = [
    {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3},
    {:a => 1, :b => 3, :c => 4}
]
compare_hash = {:a => 1}
stored_hash.some_function_here(compare_hash)
```

Should return:

```
[
   {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3},
   {:a => 1, :b => 3, :c => 4}
]
```

While this:

```
stored_hash  = [
    {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3},
    {:a => 1, :b => 3, :c => 4}
]
compare_hash = {:a => 1, :b => 3}
stored_hash.some_function_here(compare_hash)
```

Should return:

```
[
   {:a => 1, :b => 3, :c => 4}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way, using [`Array#keep_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-keep_if) and [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge)

```
stored_hash.keep_if {|hash| hash.merge(compare_hash) == hash}
```

Comment: thank you! Great answer. Would it be possible to extend this, so that you can provide an array of "compare_hashes" aswell?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
def matches(stored_hash, compare_hash)
  stored_hash.select do |h|
    h.values_at(*compare_hash.keys) == compare_hash.values
  end
end

stored_hash  = [
    {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3},
    {:a => 1, :b => 3, :c => 4}
]
compare_hash = {:a => 1}

matches(stored_hash, compare_hash)
  #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}, {:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>4}] 

compare_hash = {:a => 1, :b => 3}

matches(stored_hash, compare_hash)
  #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to monkey-patch `Array`, you're not going to call a method on `stored_hash`, but you can do this:

```
def some_function(haystack, needle)
  haystack.select do |hash|
    needle.all? { |k,v| hash[k] == v }
  end
end
```

and then call it with

```
some_function(stored_hash, compare_hash)
```

Also, note your `stored_hash` isn't a hash, it's an array; the name is a bit misleading.

Comment: you wanted to say "monkey-patch `Array`" I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
def find_matches(stored_hash, compare_hash)
  stored_hash.find_all {|h| h.to_a & compare_hash.to_a == compare_hash.to_a}
end

compare_hash = {:a=>1, :b=>2}

find_matches(stored_hash, compare_hash)
#=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}]

compare_hash = {:a=>1}

find_matches(stored_hash, compare_hash)
#=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}, {:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>4}]
```